# react-meta-tags with Wordpress API server rendering

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, facebook-opengraph, wp-api

I'm using ***Wordpress API*** as my backend CMS with a ***headless React*** frontend. The last piece I need to set up is social Open Graph Meta tags. I'm using the NPM package ***react-meta-tags*** and trying to understand how to pass the server side rendering in WP to the client side component. The [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-meta-tags) detail a Node based server render but I'm unable to translate that to my Wordpress backend.

Has anyone implemented OG tags with a WP / Headless React build?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to fill in the meta tags with dynamic data from a wordpress via API calls.

Here's an example of getting a specific post by slug (the concept is the same for other data as well) :

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch(`YOUR_WP_DOMAIN/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=YOUR_POST_SLUG&_embed`)
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    this.setState({post: data[0]});
  })
  .catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
}
```

At this point you could populate whatever meta tags you need with the data you just fetched:

```
<MetaTags>
  <title>{this.state.post.title.rendered}</title>
  <meta property="og:title" content={this.state.post.title.rendered} />
  <meta property="og:image" content={post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes.full.source_url} />
</MetaTags>
```

Hopefully that helps a bit. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Hi heres and example with using Yoast SEO and the plugin WP REST Yoast Meta and React Helmet

It sets the Meta content dynamically when someone fills the forms out on the backend of wordpress

I thought i'd answer this because i was stuck on the subject for quite a while i'm using axios to get the API data.

```
{Object.keys(home).length ? (


        <Helmet>


        <title>{home.yoast_meta[4].content}</title>

        <meta name={home.yoast_meta[0].name} content={home.yoast_meta[0].content} />
        <meta property={home.yoast_meta[2].property} content={home.yoast_meta[2].content} />
        <meta property={home.yoast_meta[3].property} content={home.yoast_meta[3].content} />
        <meta property={home.yoast_meta[4].property} content={home.yoast_meta[4].content} />
        <meta property={home.yoast_meta[5].property} content={home.yoast_meta[5].content} />
        <meta property={home.yoast_meta[8].property} content={home.yoast_meta[8].content} />
        <meta property={home.yoast_meta[9].property} content={home.yoast_meta[9].content} />
        <meta property={home.yoast_meta[10].property} content={home.yoast_meta[10].content} />




       </Helmet>

      ) : ""}
```